# So my problem in this is that I cannot seem to add a void function in my code

Tags: java

I want to insert a void function in my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class javellana {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input String: ");
    String str = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Input character: ");
    char str1 = scan.next().charAt(0);

    int num = str.length();         
    int i;

    for (i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {            
      if (str1 == str.charAt(i)) {
        System.out.println("The character " + str1 + " you intput is " + i);
        break;
      }
    }                                                                       
  }
}
```

That is my code and I want to add a void function starting in "for". I want the for loop to be in a void function but I can't seem to do it. How do I fix this?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Perhaps you could show (in code) what you mean by _"adding a void function"_

Answer (score 1):

```
public class javellana {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input String: ");
        String str = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input character: ");
        char str1 = scan.next().charAt(0);
        int num = str.length();         

        tt(num,str1,str);

    }

    static void tt(int num , char str1, String str)
    {

        for(int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (str1 == str.charAt(i)) {
                System.out.println("The character " + str1 + " you intput is " + i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

> Apart from the code, what you wanna achieve from this is still
>   unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a void method as static and use it directly in main method.

```
public class javellana {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input String: ");
        String str = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input character: ");
        char str1 = scan.next().charAt(0);

        int num = str.length();
        int i;
        func(str, str1);
    }

    static void func(String str, char str1) {
        int num = str.length();
        for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (str1 == str.charAt(i)) {
                System.out.println("The character " + str1 + " you intput is " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

You can simply use `System.out.println(str.lastIndexOf(str1));` line, instead of the entire for loop for your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public class javellana {

  String str;
  char str1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input String: ");
        str = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input character: ");
        str1 = scan.next().charAt(0);

        func(); // call function here


    }

    static void func() {
        int num = str.length();
        for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (str1 == str.charAt(i)) {
                System.out.println("The character " + str1 + " you intput is " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try this for change

Answer (score 0):

If

> adding a void function

means adding(declaring) another method(function) in `public static void main(String){}`;

then this is not allowed.

What you can do is; create an anonymous class or functional interface (Java 8). Which is not exactly what you want but somehow..

Answer (score 0):

`main()` is **static** method, so only **static** method can be used from it.

Instead of using for loop, you can use **String.lastIndexOf()** method.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Input String: ");
        String str = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Input character: ");
        char ch = scan.next().charAt(0);

        lastIndexOf(str, ch);
    }
}

private static void lastIndexOf(String str, char ch) {
    int i = str.lastIndexOf(ch);

    if (i >= 0)
        System.out.println("The character " + ch + " you input is " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a method within a method. 
Currently, you're in main method.
But you can call as many methods you want from a method.

But there's some restriction. you can't call the nonstatic method within a static method.
Therefore the @pkgajulapalli [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53862664/7098046) is probably correct.